Is SQL .bak file compressed without explicitly stating to compress?
I use the following script to make a .bak of a production database and save it to a test server where it can be restored if needed. The script does not state to compress the file. Running SQL Server 2019 Enterprise.
BACKUP DATABASE [PINK] 
    TO DISK = N'\\TestServer\Transfer\PINK.bak' 
    WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'PINK', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, CHECKSUM
GO

DECLARE @backupSetId AS int

SELECT @backupSetId = position 
FROM msdb..backupset 
WHERE database_name = N'PINK' 
  AND backup_set_id = (SELECT MAX(backup_set_id) 
                       FROM msdb..backupset 
                       WHERE database_name = N'PINK')

IF @backupSetId IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''PINK'' not found.', 16, 1) 
END

RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
    FROM DISK = N'\\TestServer\Transfer\PINK.bak' 
    WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND
GO

The .bak lands on the test server and depending on where you look in Explorer it is either 162GB or 154GB:

To save some space I tried to compress the .bak by adding COMPRESSION to the script:
BACKUP DATABASE [PINK] 
    TO DISK = N'\\TestServer\Transfer\PINK.bak' 
    WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'PINK', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10, CHECKSUM
GO

DECLARE @backupSetId AS int

SELECT @backupSetId = position 
FROM msdb..backupset 
WHERE database_name = N'PINK' 
  AND backup_set_id = (SELECT MAX(backup_set_id) 
                       FROM msdb..backupset 
                       WHERE database_name = N'PINK')

IF @backupSetId IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''PINK'' not found.', 16, 1) 
END

RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
    FROM DISK = N'\\TestServer\Transfer\PINK.bak' 
    WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND
GO

After executing with the COMMPRESSION command included, it landed at the same size on the test server. I checked the .ndf and .mdf files and they total 770GB or 732GB depending on where you look. Plus it includes about 23GB of index info.

Is this .bak already compressed even though I have not stated to do so?

The other answers explain the probable cause, that the server configuration to compress backups is enabled, so you're getting it whether you asked for it or not. If this is the cause, you'll see that the row in msdb.dbo.backupset that corresponds to the backup will have compression_algorithm populated ('MS_XPRESS'), and compressed_backup_size will probably be different from backup_size. If the backup wasn't compressed, then compression_algorithm will be NULL and backup_size and compressed_backup_size will be the same.
SELECT backup_size, compressed_backup_size, compression_algorithm
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
  WHERE { your where clause };

You can also check the Compressed column in RESTORE HEADERONLY:
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
  FROM DISK = '\\TestServer\Transfer\PINK.bak'
  WITH FILE = @backupSetId;

If the setting is disabled, just enable it:
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'backup compression default', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;

I don't know why you wouldn't have this on, or why you wouldn't want compression to just always happen, unless you are trying to maximize final compression by using much more intensive/effective 3rd party options to compress an uncompressed backup. You're certainly no further ahead in terms of required space, I/O, and bandwidth, and I don't know how much more effective 7-Zip and others might be today anyway.

But there is another possibility: maybe your data just doesn't compress well, or is already compressed (using page, row, or columnstore). In this case, backup compression might have little or even zero effect; if so, you're unlikely to see much of a difference between backups WITH COMPRESSION and without.

A couple of notes about appending multiple backups to a single .bak:

Just don't do it. This "efficiency" dates back to physical tapes and causes nothing but confusion (and even data corruption, as people just run a restore without realizing they get the first/oldest file by default). Much better practice to always use WITH INIT and make output files unique and self-documenting by embedding timestamps; this can be automated with various free tools, like DBATools Backup-DbaDatabase (using -TimeStampFormat) and Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Backup (using @FileName = N'...{Year}{Month}{Day}_{Hour}{Minute}{Second}...').
A more relevant example of confusion: If you compressed the first file in the backup, subsequent files will say Compressed = 1 in RESTORE HEADERONLY regardless of whether you explicitly say WITH COMPRESSION - and msdb agrees. I was expecting an error (which you get if you try the other way: no compression and then compression). From everything I can see, those later backups are compressed. This is actually a third potential explanation for your current scenario: your first backup in PINK.BAK was compressed, so all the rest are inheriting that option.


I would have considered this a single backup since it is only one database. Are you considering it multiple because of the multiple mdf and ndf files? Are you recommending that each mdf and ndf have its own .bak?

@Don No, you can back up the same database over and over again to the same .bak file. If you don't use WITH INIT (which your question shows, but I don't know if that's what you did / always do), then the .bak file will contain one additional backup each time. It will get bigger, and you could choose any of the backups within for restore operations (using FILE = n where n represents the sequence of the backups taken). I just don't think this is a sensible way to organize backups.

Compression can be active as the default behavior.
You can run this query to check for it:
SELECT value
FROM   sys.configurations
WHERE  name = 'backup compression default'

0 means that backup compression is off, 1 means that backup compression is on.
For more info, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-configure-the-backup-compression-default-server-configuration-option

SSMS > Right click on server-Instance > Properties>Database Settings >
Compress backup.
Either you can check default status or change it.


